# Is the word “classless” neutral in its implication, or does it have a derogatory tone?

Tags: meaning, adjectives, connotation, nonsubjective

I was drawn to the word, “classless” in Carolyn Hax’s answer to a reader in the counseling corner of Washington Post (June 7), which comes under the title, [“How do you get back at a loudmouth? By letting the boor talk.”](http://www.washingtonpost.com/lifestyle/style/carolyn-hax-how-do-you-get-back-at-a-loudmouth-by-letting-the-boor-talk/2014/06/05/9807e5ce-e04a-11e3-8dcc-d6b7fede081a_story.html)

> Asker: What to do, as a full-grown adult, when **a classless coward**
>   makes a loud, public and derogatory comment about your mother after
>   your unknowing mother walked out of the restaurant, where this person
>   and party were coincidentally seated near us?
>
> Carolyn Hax: If you want to take down a “**classless coward**,” then
>   give her a megaphone and let her dismantle herself. With no amplifying
>   equipment handy, it’s okay just to let rude people think they won, to
>   have faith that people of character know a boor when they hear one and
>   to trust you won’t implode waiting for the vengeful urges to pass.

I’m inclined to associate the word “classless” in the above quote with the Japanese expression, “どこの馬の骨とも解らぬ人-Dokono-uma-no hone"- A person like a bone of horse who comes from an unknown family - meaning a person whose family line and social class are unknown, therefore boorish or untrustworthy. Yesteryears’ parents wouldn’t have agreed their daughter to marry a lad like a “bone of horse”.

However as far as I checked CED and OED, the meaning of “classless” is just neutral:

CED defines ‘classless’ as;

1. *Not belonging to a particular social class*
2. *Having no different social classes*

OED defines it as;

1. (Of a society) *not divided into social classes*
2. *Not showing obvious signs of belonging to a particular social class*

Is the word, “classless” just neutral on its implication, or does it have a somewhat negative tone depending on the occasion, as observed in the above example?

Comment: It is definitely negative in the USA, the opposite of *classy*, unless strictly dealing with classes in society (which is not the most common use of the word here).

Comment: It can be used neutrally, but it is usually used in the sense of being vulgar, behaviorally appropriate to the lower class.

Comment: Consider also the word "gentle", which originally derives from an association between good character/behaviour and being well-born, i.e. of good social class. I'm pretty sure "classy/classless" was at one time a similar association. Most people who use "gentle" in the sense of "non-violent" aren't making any association with social class, and I think many (maybe not most) people who use "classy"/"classless" in the sense "good/bad character" aren't either. I'm surprised the dictionaries don't give the derived meaning, it's perfectly intelligible to me as a speaker of British English.

Comment: It is perfectly possible to use "classless" in a neutral sense, in the way that a social commentator might. e.g. "Speaking in a classless accent the visitor gave no clues as to his origins". Nowadays, I suspect that that is by far the more common sense in which the term is used. Derogatorily describing someone as "classless", meaning that they lacked poise and polish, would mostly be considered, at the very least politically incorrect, if not downright rude.

Answer (score 7):

Merriam Webster lists a third sense

**3**:  crass, boorish *classless behavior*

The article is using it in the third sense. I rarely encounter the word used of a person in a non-insulting way.

Comment: Absolutely.  Classless is a super negative term in the US almost all of the time.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd Except in the sense that we live in a classless society, and anyone who suggests otherwise is engaging in class warfare. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_society and https://www.google.com/search?q=class+warfare&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=Asd&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=sb&source=lnms&tbm=nws&sa=X&ei=ah-TU-KbDoyEqgbRooK4CQ&ved=0CAoQ_AUoAw&biw=1264&bih=659

Comment: @WayfaringStranger - completely agree but that is not common usage and very easy to differ with context.

Answer (score 7):

It is being used in a negative sense in that example, but I think the positive sense is also familiar to just about everyone in the English-speaking world from John Lennon's lyrics in *Working Class Hero*:

> And you think you're so clever and classless and free
>
> But you're still fucking peasants as far as I can see

Answer (score 5):

In the US, *classless* is usually the opposite of *classy*, unless strictly dealing with classes in society (which is not the most common use of the word here). Some uses of *class*:

> - "He does everything *with class*," Blake said. "He answers his questions very carefully, very politically correct, and he doesn't really put himself in a bad situation where he has to try to dig himself out." - [NYT](http://www.nytimes.com/2005/02/04/sports/football/04mcnabb.html?fta=y&_r=0), of Donovan McNabb
> - ...guys that played on the team with him, you would hear the same statement, that he is *a classy guy* from top to bottom. - NYT
> - It was all plain as day and made its own argument: San Francisco 49ers head coach Jim Harbaugh is a *classless* thug.

However

> - She asks people if Sweden really is a *classless society* and badgers union officials about why the labor movement is so conservative. NYT

Answer (score 0):

...***meaning a person who’s*** [sic] ***family line and social class are unknown, therefore boorish or untrustworthy***.

Americans do not have the historical social distinction/caste system found in other cultures, including Japan.  Notably, there is a societal pride for those who have come from difficult circumstances and have succeeded economically, educationally...it is part of our 'melting pot' mentality.  Your quote refers to one person, not her family, or lineage but her personal actions.

The term 'classless' is not always negative, and in fact can be used to show admiration for someone who refuses to follow sociatal norms but succeeds nonetheless.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It is bad practice to correct a quoted passage; it undermines the provenance with respect to searching, and the understanding the speaker's ESL status.  In this case, a '(sic)' notation is the proper method for drawing attention to an error.

Comment: Mari-Lou A. I was careless and unaware of having put “a person ‘who’s.” It should be ‘whose.’ Thank you for pointing out the mistake.

Comment: @ThirdNews, quoting via “...person who’s [sic] family...” is appropriate if you wish to call attention to the error and disclaim responsibility for it.  But quoting via “...person [whose] family...” (ie, using brackets to show that a word has been changed) would be more appropriate here.  There is no particular reason to highlight the error. -1